# Returning previous/last values based on conditional statements

Tags: r, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have a dataset with multiple VCs, Funds, Performance, Year and Fund Size.
Each FUND has a Performance. To test whether there is performance persistence, I want to find the performance of the previous/predecessor fund("PreviousPerformance"). The PreviousPerformance is the performance of the prior FUND of the same VC. Therefore, the Year determines which funds were started first, second and so on.

```
VC            FUND      Performance   Year     FundSize
A Partners    A         0.30          2005        1 
B Capital     B5        0.20          2008        2
B Capital     B4        0.10          2003        3
B Capital     B3        0.25          2001        4
B Capital     B2        0.20          2001        5
B Capital     B1        0.10          2000        6
```

For example: FUND "B5" has a PreviousPerformance of 0.1, which is the performance of B4.

Sometimes, it is unclear which fund was the last fund. For example B4 has two previous funds, B2 and B3, which were both founded in 2001. In this case, I want the PreviousPerformance to be the performance of the FUND with largest FundSize (for B4 this is B5). In case a  FUND has no predecessor, PreviousPerformance = "-"

In the end, the dataset should look something like this.

```
 VC            FUND      Performance   Year     FundSize  PreviousPerformance
 A Partners    A         0.30          2005        1                       -
 B Capital     B5        0.20          2008        2                     0.1
 B Capital     B4        0.10          2003        3                     0.2
 B Capital     B3        0.25          2001        4                     0.1
 B Capital     B2        0.20          2001        5                     0.1
 B Capital     B1        0.10          2000        6                       -
```

I have no idea which functions to use for this kind of problem, does anyone have a suggestion?

### Code used for example:

```
FundPerformance = data.table(VC = c("A Partners", rep("B Capital",5)), 
     FUND = c("A","B5","B4","B3","B2","B1"), 
     Performance = c(0.3,0.2,0.1,0.25,0.2,0.1), 
     Year= c(2005,2008,2003,2001,2001,2000), 
     FundSize=c(1:6),
     PreviousPerformance = c ("-",0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,"-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following. But I am not a frequent `data.table` user, so someone else may have a cleaner solution.

```
# set up data
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(VC = c("A Partners", rep("B Capital",5)), 
                 Fund = c("A","B5","B4","B3","B2","B1"), 
                 Performance = c(0.3,0.2,0.1,0.25,0.2,0.1), 
                 Year= c(2005,2008,2003,2001,2001,2000), 
                 FundSize=c(1:6),
                 PreviousPerformance = c (NA,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,NA))
setkey(dt, VC, Year)

# find performance for largest fund within each VC each year
dt[, PreviousPerformanceII:=Performance[FundSize==max(FundSize)], keyby=key(dt)]
dtUnique <- unique(dt, keyby=key(dt))
dtUnique <- dtUnique[, list(VC, Year, PreviousPerformanceII)]

# rolling join to pick up last year's performance
dtUnique[, Year:=Year+1]
setkey(dtUnique, VC, Year)
dtNew <- dtUnique[dt, roll=TRUE]

# clean up data
dtNew$i.PreviousPerformanceII <- NULL
setkey(dtNew, VC, Year)
dtNew
```